# A faster discrete Laplacian than scipy.ndimage.filters.laplace for small arrays

Tags: python, c++, numpy, filter

My spends the vast bulk of its computational time in [`scipy.ndimage.filters.laplace()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.laplace.html)

The main advantage of `scipy` and `numpy` is vectorised calculation in `C/C++` wrapped in `python`. 
[`scipy.ndimage.filters.laplace()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.laplace.html) is derived from `_nd_image.correlate1d` which is
 part of the optimised library [`nd_image.h`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/ndimage/src/nd_image.h)

Is there any faster method of doing this across an array of size `10-100`?

**Definition** *Laplace Filter* - ignoring division

- `a[i-1] - 2*a[i] + a[i+1]`
- *Optional* Can ideally wrap around boundary `a[n-1] - 2*a[n-1] + a[0]` for `n=a.shape[0]`

Comment: *"is however, written in pure `python`"* - Are you sure? To me, it looks like its only a wrapper around some c++ functions, the time spent in the python code is probably negligible.

Comment: I just realised that you're totally correct `_nd_image.correlate1d` is part of [`nd_image.h`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/ndimage/src/nd_image.h) I will edit the question a little in that case

Comment: For explicit methods of solving your **Definition** above, there is a nice overview of differenct languages where fortran with f2py is optimal: http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/PerformancePython. Maybe a faster method to solving the Laplacian might be needed, where I think something like a multigrid method would be the state of the art, for example could you use https://github.com/pyamg/pyamg and set RHS to zero? Or maybe the filter/convolution is the limiting step so this isn't worth it.

Comment: see below - I've figured the solution without having to recode anything - your method would be ideal for large arrays but for `10-100` length arrays `python` gets in the way

Answer (score 2):

The problem was rooted in `scipy`'s excellent error handling and debugging. However, in the instance the user knows what they're doing it just provides excess overhead.

This code below strips all the `python` clutter in the back end of `scipy` and directly accesses the `C++` function to get a `~6x` speed up!

```
laplace == Mine ? True
testing timings...
array size 10
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.7 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.3 µs per loop
array size 100
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.7 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.5 µs per loop
array size 100000
1000 loops, best of 3: 413 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 404 µs per loop
```

### Code

```
from scipy import ndimage
from scipy.ndimage import _nd_image
import numpy as np

laplace_filter = np.asarray([1, -2, 1], dtype=np.float64)

def fastLaplaceNd(arr):
    output = np.zeros(arr.shape, 'float64')
    if arr.ndim > 0:
        _nd_image.correlate1d(arr, laplace_filter, 0, output, 1, 0.0, 0)
        if arr.ndim == 1: return output
        for ax in xrange(1, arr.ndim):
            output += _nd_image.correlate1d(arr, laplace_filter, ax, output, 1, 0.0, 0)
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = np.random.random(10)
    test = (ndimage.filters.laplace(arr, mode='wrap') == fastLaplace(arr)).all()
    assert test
    print "laplace == Mine ?", test
    print 'testing timings...'
    print "array size 10"
    %timeit ndimage.filters.laplace(arr, mode='wrap')
    %timeit fastLaplace(arr)
    print 'array size 100'
    arr = np.random.random(100)
    %timeit ndimage.filters.laplace(arr, mode='wrap')
    %timeit fastLaplace(arr)
    print "array size 100000"
    arr = np.random.random(100000)
    %timeit ndimage.filters.laplace(arr, mode='wrap')
    %timeit fastLaplace(arr)
```

Comment: As a side comment to speed up large arrays where python overhead become negligible the following GPU accelerated method should work https://github.com/rcloud/PyOpenCL-OpenCL-Programming-Guide-Examples/blob/master/laplace/jacobian-2d.py